# COUNT over multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I've searched the site and found a few similar questions but nothing that addresses this issue specifically.  As such the answers don't quite fit this problem.  I have a table with 12 columns.  Six of those twelve columns ( one, two, three, four, five, six) have ratings expressed as numerical values 1 through 100.  So I may have a row ( rowId=7 ) that will have a unique numerical value in each of those six columns.  What I want to do is list the numerical values by the frequency that they appear, treating all six columns as one total.  I don't care about the frequency of a rating in column one vs column four.  I just need the frequency across all columns.  It would seem as if UNION is the way to go, but UNION cannot then be sorted using ORDER BY.  I've flummoxed through several different, and ultimately unsuccessful variations of queries.  Rather than itemize those failures here I will just ask if anyone knows of a way to do this.

Comment: What do you mean by "treating all six columns as one total"?

Comment: What I mean is that I need to list each of the possible values, 1 thru 100, ordered by how often they appear in any of the six columns.  It doesn't matter if it's in column 1 or column 4.  I need them ordered by the total number of appearances across all six columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
SELECT V, COUNT(*) C
FROM (
    SELECT one V FROM your_table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT two FROM your_table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT three FROM your_table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT four FROM your_table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT five FROM your_table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT six FROM your_table
) Q
GROUP BY V
ORDER BY C DESC;
```

[[SQL Fiddle]](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b262/3)

This will give you each distinct value, together with the number of times it appears (regardless of the column).

Comment: This is odd.  It's close, but there are two problems.  While it does work in your fiddle it throws an error when I run it on my live database.  I'm pretty sure I can iron that part out, but the issue is that the result generated by the fiddle isn't what I need.  Based on the table created in your fiddle the result would need to be something like 

0 
5
10
20
25
30
50

Or something like that as 0 occurs the most times and 5,10,20,25,and 30 all appear twice, and 50 appears once.  I need the full list of values ordered by the number of times the occur in any of the six columns.

Comment: @BlindFish What error does it throw? Beside that, why do you expect (for example) 10 to be before 20, when 20 is more frequent? BTW, 10 doesn't appear twice. Do you actually want to sort on value and not count?

Comment: Correction to previous comment.  I did iron out the syntax error when running on the live DB but the results made zero sense.  It returned 8  results in two columns, TOTAL and C.  In the TOTAL column are 8 values all between 100 and 200, and in the C column it lists 1 every time.  I have no idea if it thinks that "1" appears each of those 8 amount of times ( impossible ), or if it thinks that the only values in the table are all out of range ( > 100 ) and only appear once.  This is also impossible.

Comment: @BlindFish Let me put it differently: do you want to count a value at most once per row, even when more than one field (in the same row) contains the same value?

Comment: @BlindFish Obviously, I don't have access to your database, so please concentrate on explaining what's wrong with my SQL Fiddle example - that's the only way I can understand what you actually want...

Comment: You are correct, 10 does only appear once.  I missed that.  I thought I saw it twice.  My mistake.  But the result still only gives three values 50, 20, 30, and gives them a count of 3, 2, 1 respectively.  50 only appears once, and 25 does not  make the list even though it appears twice.

Comment: @BlindFish Please read the SQL Fiddle more carefully - you'll see: `25 2`.

Comment: I just played with the fiddle a bit and now understand what it is doing. What you are doing is summing the rows as Total, and then counting how many times the sum appears as C.  I don't need the rows summed.  I need the frequency of each individual rating.  The result should be a list of all possible ratings from 1 thru 100 ( or at least all that are used ), ordered by how many times they appear in any of those six columns.  So, given that I just adjusted your fiddle and rebuilt the schema, the result would be something like 22 (3 times), 25 (twice), 20 (twice), 5 (twice) etc.

Comment: Just adding that I tried to be much more polite and grateful in that last comment but I ran out of characters and had to take everything out to get the main points in.  I do very much appreciate your help.

Comment: @BlindFish I'm not summing anything (I did initially in the deleted answer, before I understood a little better what you want). Are you perhaps looking at my old answer (that I deleted and then edited before undeleting)? And no worries about etiquette, you are doing fine :)

Comment: Indeed I was.  I was playing with the old fiddle and didn't realize that you had created a new one.  What you have now is exactly right.  Thank you very much for the help.  I really do appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rather efficient way to do this:

```
select (case when n.n = 1 then t.one
             when n.n = 2 then t.two
             when n.n = 3 then t.three
             when n.n = 4 then t.four
             when n.n = 5 then t.five
             when n.n = 6 then t.six
        end) as col, count(*) as cnt
from t cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all
      select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6
     ) n
group by (case when n.n = 1 then t.one
               when n.n = 2 then t.two
               when n.n = 3 then t.three
               when n.n = 4 then t.four
               when n.n = 5 then t.five
               when n.n = 6 then t.six
          end)
```

When you use `union` (or `union all`) to concatenate the different columns, each subquery uses a separate pass through the data.  This alternative method joins the table to a numbers table, reading the table only once.  It then uses the `case` statement to choose which column, based on the number.

The final step is simply to do the aggregation to get the count.

Comment: Can you unpack that a bit for me?  I'm reading that as needing to create the CASE with n.n being each value from 1 thru 100 but that can't be right.  Could you please explain what's happening in that query?